Natural deduction trees with subproofs in boxes
I've looked at https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/ and at the documentation of the packages linked there and don't see anything for setting the kind of proof trees with subproofs in boxes instead of discharging assumptions:
:
This example is from Richard Bornat's Proof and Disproof in Formal Logic, and ideally I'd like to label the boxes with the assumptions. In this example I'd draw the full proof like this:

But if it's easier to put the assumptions elsewhere (e.g. outside the box) that's fine too, so long as it's clear which box they correspond to. I don't know if there is a common name for this style, unfortunately.

So, are you asking how to typeset the second image, no matter, how?

@MS-SPO Yes. And typesetting the first image is good enough, if the second one ends up being too complex.

why aren't A and B marked as inferred?

Gentzen style proofs don't usually use boxes or scope lines to mark subproofs, so I don't know of a ready-made solution. The textbook's author might have one, so it might be worth enquiring, but, of course, it may not use TeX.
So any method is likely to be somewhat ad hoc unless you are prepared to (or are willing to hire somebody to) write a tailored package for this style. Which method to use probably depends partly on the complexity of your proofs, partly on the number you need to typeset and partly on your existing familiarity with the various techniques involved.
I present two solutions. Neither is perfect. I'm going to explain the one I wrote second first because I think it is probably the better way to go, but I'm certainly not confident of this and the one I wrote first is likely to be more flexible.
Method 1 (written second): ebproof
This method was inspired by MS-SPO's bussproofs answer.
ebproof supports traditional Gentzen-style proofs and is essentially an updated and more flexible version of the tried and true bussproofs. What is of particular interest to us is that it supports a \rewrite option. This is intended to facilitate constructing proofs bit-by-bit in beamer presentations, but we are going to use it to box the sub-proofs instead. This turns out to be very easy to do and provides a comparatively elegant solution to the box issue.

The disadvantage of this approach is that manual adjustments are required to achieve the target spacing.

Vertical spacing tweaks To get the two disjuncts aligned, for example, you have to add explicit spacing. Doubtless this could be at least partly automatised, but I suspect it will remain something of a bugbear.
Horizontal adjustments Moreover, if you want to add rule labels to your inference lines, you also need to move these if the rule directly follows a sub-proof and the conclusion of the sub-proof is narrower than its widest line. Since this will frequently be the case when sub-proofs are involved, this is less than ideal. Again, at least some degree of automatisation is surely possible, but it is certainly not out-of-the-box.

Anyway, here's the proof itself:
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{A \lor B}
  \hypo{A \vdash}

So far, so standard. See ebproof's very nice documentation for details of the commands. Now, however, we need some hackery. Without this, A \vdash will not align with B \vdash but be just above the conclusion of the first sub-proof. That's standard, but not what the book you're using demands.
  \infer[no rule]1{\vrule height 23.5pt width 0pt}

I tried using \strut, but that is too coarse-grained, so the 23.5pt is just the result of trial-and-error until it looked roughly right.
  \infer[no rule]1{A}

Perfectly standard if only it had the usual rule. But ebproof makes it easy to remove it, though I've no idea why your book doesn't mark this as inferred. Now for another hack.
  \rewrite{\fbox{\box\treebox}}

This is the \rewrite. ebproof puts the sub-proof into a box, \treebox so it can be easily erased for use on beamer slides. This is very, very nice. All we need to do is put it into an \fbox. The rest is standard until we end the second sub-proof.
  \hypo{B \vdash}
  \infer[no rule]1{B}
  \hypo{\lnot B}
  \infer2{\lfalse}
  \infer1{A}

Another use of that beamer feature.
  \rewrite{\fbox{\box\treebox}}

Now for the horizontal kludge. If we don't add horizontal space, the name of the rule overwrites the sub-proof box. Again, 20pt is just the outcome of trial-and-error. (But you could certainly automate this as you could measure the box and store the result earlier.)
  \infer3[\hskip 20pt$\lor$ elim]{A}
\end{prooftree}

Complete code below.
Method 2 (written first): forest
In essence, we can think of the proofs as upward-growing trees. You'd think those would be the ordinary kind, but most formal trees grow into the ground. (Including, of course, tableaux, so logic is not immune to this absurdity.)
Anyway, given it is basically a tree, I'd use a tree-drawing package of some kind. My favourite non-specialised package of this kind is forest. You specify the tree using a standard bracket syntax. (At least, it is standard for linguists - not sure logicians have such a thing.)

Like method 1 above, this approach has advantages and disadvantages.

Pros Several.

Adjustments to spacing can be easily automatised.
Full range of tikz styles readily available.
Very concise specification of proofs in document.


Cons Quite a number.

More elaborate setup (but one-time only - could also be loaded from file for use in multiple documents).
Markup is less semantic and sometimes inaccurate (but this could probably be fixed).
Line doesn't extend fully when sub-proof is boxed (actually this goes for ebproof, too, but the difference is hidden), currently no way to label inferences (but could be added if required).
It is also likely to slow compilation significantly if you need many proofs in the same document (but this can be greatly mitigated by externalisation with e.g. memoize).



The following provides a number of styles to make drawing the tree easier.

bdfl: a style to specify in the tree's preamble, which sets things up.
ass : premises must be marked this way. This is not optional - the code depends on the premises being designated correctly.
subproof box=<comma-separated list of nodes>: the lists must use relative node names. Sorry about this. A more fully developed solution would be more flexible, but this standardisation makes it easier to produce something usable (relatively) quickly.

Here's a slightly more detailed how-to:
\begin{forest}

Start the environment. Blank lines are forbidden within this environment.
  bdfl,

Tell forest to apply the proof style specified in the preamble.
  [A  % conclusion

Specify the proof backwards from conclusion to premises. The conclusion is the root.
    [A \lor B
    ]
    [A
      [A \vdash, ass, subproof box={!c,!u},

This is one of our two assumptions, so we specify ass. This is typically a good place to specify what should be boxed.
subproof box={!c,!u}

adds two nodes. We need curly brackets/braces to protect the comma. We could use a different delimiter, but the intuitive appropriateness of commas seemed to me to outweigh the inconvenience of needing the brackets.
!c is the current node. ! means this is a relative node name i.e. it specifies a node relative to the current node. So this says, the node which is this-current-node relative to the-current-node. That's cumbersome, but !c is short enough. !u is the-parent-node of the-current-node. Only two nodes to box here, so we're done.
      ]
    ]
    [A
      [\lfalse
        [B
          [B \vdash, ass, subproof box={!c,!u,!uu,!us,!uuu},

Again, ass to mark it as a premise. This time the list to box is a bit more complicated. !uu is the-parent-of-the-parent-of-the-current-node i.e. this node's grandparent. !uuu is this node's great-grandparent. s is a sibling. So !us is the sibling of the parent of the current node.
          ]
        ]
        [\lnot B
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

That's it. forest syntax can be very concise.
Complete listings
Code for ebproof:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726832/
\usepackage{ebproof}
\newcommand* \lfalse{\mathord{\bot}}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{A \lor B}
  \hypo{A \vdash}
  \infer[no rule]1{\vrule height 23.5pt width 0pt}
  \infer[no rule]1{A}
  \rewrite{\fbox{\box\treebox}}
  \hypo{B \vdash}
  \infer[no rule]1{B}
  \hypo{\lnot B}
  \infer2{\lfalse}
  \infer1{A}
  \rewrite{\fbox{\box\treebox}}
  \infer3[\hskip 20pt$\lor$ elim]{A}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}

Code for forest:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand* \lfalse{\mathord{\bot}}
\forestset{% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726832/
  declare boolean={pr}{0},
  declare boolean={first infer}{0},
  declare boolean={boxed}{0},
  declare toks={inferred from}{},
  declare toks={in box}{},
  ass/.style={%
    tier=ass,
    pr,
    delay={!u.first infer},
  },
  bdfl/.style={%
    for tree={%
      grow'=90,
      math content,
      no edge,
      l sep'=0pt,
      l'=0pt,
      inner xsep=2pt,
      inner ysep=4pt,
    },
    before drawing tree={%
      delay={%
        where={%
          > O_= O |   {n children}{0} {first infer}
        }{}{%
          tikz+={%
            \draw (!{first}.south west) ++(0pt,-.5pt) coordinate (a) -- (a -| !{last}.south east) ;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  to box/.style={%
    #1.boxed,
    inferred from+=(#1),
    #1.in box/.register=temptoksa,
  },
  subproof box/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      temptoksa/.option=name,
      split={#1}{,}{to box},
    },
    before computing xy={%
      tikz+/.process={%
        OOw2{inferred from}{in box}{%
          \node [fit=##1,draw,inner xsep=1.5pt,inner ysep=-2pt] (##2) {};
        }%
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  bdfl,
  [A
    [A \lor B
    ]
    [A
      [A \vdash, ass, subproof box={!c,!u},
      ]
    ]
    [A
      [\lfalse
        [B
          [B \vdash, ass, subproof box={!c,!u,!uu,!us,!uuu},
          ]
        ]
        [\lnot B
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


why is logic plagued by this determination to eschew standardisation of any kind when it comes to the kinds of proofs most widely used in teaching? do authors think nobody will buy their books if they don't distinguish themselves by the use of some unique diagrammatic element? do publishers refuse to consider texts which don't invent a new way of representing the elements of proofs? I have no idea how PDFs containing logic are going to get tagged when we all use these ad hoc solutions because we have to treat every single system as a special case.

OP has nice rounded horizontal lines.

@Simd I would have thought that was the least of this answer's deficiencies. it is easy enough to alter the line endings if that's desired, though. you can just add a rounded cap to edge. personally, I don't think I would do that. such things are generally square and the OP's image is clearly not a 'tidy' version, so hard to tell what's wanted and what incidental imperfection.

Great new approach +1

@MS-SPO thanks. I was spurred to write it by your answer. I remembered something about boxes in ebproof, which I don't think bussproofs has. that part of it works surprisingly neatly, given it isn't the intended result at all. too bad about the spacing.

Thank you! "What is of particular interest to us is that it supports a \rewrite option. This is intended to facilitate constructing proofs bit-by-bit in beamer presentations" I missed this previously and it will be useful to me as well.

@AlexeyRomanov yes and it is much easier to manipulate than forest's boxes! (and I say that as a fan of forest.)

Here is another way to do it using just plain Tikz. Let's go through the codes structure to produce this:

Mixing text with tikz
No magic here:

start with some text
draw some tikz-thingies (on the same baseline)
continue text

\begin{document}
Just typeset 
 \tikz{
    \node[fill=cyan!20] (D) {\AorB \hspace{1em} \Abox \hspace{1em} \Bbox};
    \draw (D.south west) -- (D.south east);
    \node [anchor=north,fill=orange!20] at (D.south) {$A$};
 }
 as you normally would.
\end{document}

I put some colors, to better see the elements (remove the fills later):

have a (cyan) node (D), which takes some "obscure" typeset Latex
draw a line from its lower left to its lower right
place another node (orange) node using anchor points south and north

The argument of node (D)
Node arguments take any valid Latex code. To better see its structure, I introduced some newcommands to spell out {\AorB \hspace{1em} \Abox \hspace{1em} \Bbox}; which all are ... Latex statements after expansion.
Macro \Bbox
That's the box starting with "B", to the right. It becomes a Latex statement because it follows this structure:

\fbox{\tikz{ someTikzStatements } }

\newcommand\Bbox[0]{%
 \fbox{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node                    (A) at (0,0) {$B \vdash$};
    \node[anchor=north west] (B) at (A.south) {\strut$B \quad \neg B$};
    \draw (B.south west) -- (B.south east);
    \node                    (C) at ([yshift=-3mm]B.south) {\strut$\bot$};
    \draw (C.south west) -- (C.south east);
    \node                    (D) at ([yshift=-3mm]C.south) {$A$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}}

The Tikz code follows the same idea as shown above adding:

some yshifts for better read-ability
some \strut commands for a uniform vertical typesetting

Macro \Abox
Is a copy from \Bbox with all the drawing statements removed. (You can generalize these things more, but for the question it's just fine enough.)
Macro \AorB
... shouldn't be magical at all ...

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\AorB[0]{$A \lor B$}
%
\newcommand\Abox[0]{%
 \fbox{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[text width=10mm]
    \node                    (A) at (0,0) {$A \vdash$};
    \node[anchor=north west] (B) at (A.south) {\strut};
    \node                    (C) at ([yshift=-3mm]B.south) {\strut};
    \node                    (D) at ([yshift=-3mm]C.south) {$A$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}}
%
\newcommand\Bbox[0]{%
 \fbox{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node                    (A) at (0,0) {$B \vdash$};
    \node[anchor=north west] (B) at (A.south) {\strut$B \quad \neg B$};
    \draw (B.south west) -- (B.south east);
    \node                    (C) at ([yshift=-3mm]B.south) {\strut$\bot$};
    \draw (C.south west) -- (C.south east);
    \node                    (D) at ([yshift=-3mm]C.south) {$A$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
Just typeset 
 \tikz{
    \node[fill=cyan!20] (D) {\AorB \hspace{1em} \Abox \hspace{1em} \Bbox};
    \draw (D.south west) -- (D.south east);
    \node [anchor=north,fill=orange!20] at (D.south) {$A$};
 }
 as you normally would.
\end{document}


BTW, you can do the same using e.g. \mbox or \makebox and some \rule statements, i.e. without any use of Tikz. Perhaps you'll need some \savebox es on your way ...

coffins .......

@cfr, that‘s even better (recently learned about it).

OP has nice rounded horizontal lines.

@Simd ... sorry? Don't get your point

If you look at OP's image, the horizontal bars have rounded ends.

Do you think so? Looks to my like an artifact from a handmade sketch: the OP should comment on this. // However, using rounded corners is a next-to-no brainer with nodes ;-)

Yes, the line ends are just an artifact.

Here is an approach, using package bussproofs and plain Latex. There are some flaws left, plus the horizontal and vertical dimensions used are just visual guesses: they certainly can be more automized.
Flow:

write text and 2 \fboxes (2nd one uses bussproofs)
use a \rule to indicate deduction
use a \makebox to take care of the rules width

Not nice, but it works ... because bussproofs doesn't seem to allow mixing with Latex.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}
 \hspace{5mm}
 $A \lor B$ \hspace{.5em}
 \fbox{\parbox[b]{2cm}{$A \vdash$\\
    \vspace{38pt}
 
    \centering{$A$}
 }}
 \hspace{.5em}
 \fbox{\parbox[b]{2cm}{$B \vdash$
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{$B$}
    \AxiomC{$\neg B$}
    \BinaryInfC{$\bot$}
    \UnaryInfC{$A$}
  \end{prooftree}}}
  
  \rule{8cm}{1pt}
  
  \makebox[8cm]{$A$}
\end{document}

